# Jquery Sort and give message correct or incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, jquery-ui

I have a list item that is sortable.

```
<div id="reImbursement_msg" style="display: none;"></div>
<div>
    <ul class="sortable reImbursementdiv  cur">
        <li id="sort_five">alpha</li>
        <li id="sort_one">beta</li>
        <li id="sort_four">gamma</li>
        <li id="sort_three">thita</li>
        <li id="sort_two">pie</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want is to display a message whenever users made a sort. Here I am trying to compare two arrays. It only shows a message as "Incorrect Order" even if the array is matching.

```
var correctOrder = ["sort_one", "sort_two", "sort_three", "sort_four", "sort_five"];
var userOrder = $(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
    return i.id
});

function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for (var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


$(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {

        if (arraysEqual(correctOrder, userOrder) == true) {
                showMsg("reImbursement_msg", "Correct Order", "success");

        } else {
            showMsg("reImbursement_msg", "Incorrect Order", "danger");
            console.log($(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
                return i.id
            }));
        }


        return true;
    }
}).disableSelection();

function showMsg(box, msg, msgStatus) {
    $("#" + box)
            .removeClass()
            .show()
            .addClass("alert alert-" + msgStatus)
            .html(msg);
}
```

I have created a pen as per request.

[Codepen link demo](https://codepen.io/Santoshah/pen/NELvxx)

Comment: You can check if they are in correct order just doing `arr1.toString() == arr2.toString()`

Comment: Could you create a CodePen or similar so readers can run the code themselves?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin I have added a codepen link. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you never update `userOrder` so the order, that is being compared, never changes. Please review:

```js
$(function() {
  var correctOrder = ["sort_one", "sort_two", "sort_three", "sort_four", "sort_five"];
  var userOrder = [];

  function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    var result = true;
    if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
      $.each(arr1, function(key, val) {
        result = result && (arr1[key] === arr2[key]);
      });
    } else {
      result = false;
    }
    console.log(arr1, arr2, result);
    return result;
  }

  function showMsg(box, msg, msgStatus) {
    $(box)
      .removeClass()
      .show()
      .addClass("alert alert-" + msgStatus)
      .html(msg);
  }

  $(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      userOrder = $(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
        return i.id
      });
      if (arraysEqual(correctOrder, userOrder)) {
        showMsg("#reImbursement_msg", "Correct Order", "success");
      } else {
        showMsg("#reImbursement_msg", "Incorrect Order", "danger");
        console.log($(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
          return i.id
        }));
      }
      return true;
    }
  }).disableSelection();

  userOrder = $(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
    return i.id
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="reImbursement_msg" style="display: none;"></div>
<div>
  <ul class="sortable reImbursementdiv cur">
    <li id="sort_five">five</li>
    <li id="sort_one">one</li>
    <li id="sort_four">four</li>
    <li id="sort_three">three</li>
    <li id="sort_two">two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You also have to be mindful of the order of operations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I agree. I already realize it but hey thanks. would like to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed the latest order from user after the sorting is done.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
  var userOrder = $(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
      return i.id
  });
      if (arraysEqual(correctOrder, userOrder) == true) {
              showMsg("reImbursement_msg", "Correct Order", "success");

      } else {
          showMsg("reImbursement_msg", "Incorrect Order", "danger");
          console.log($(".sortable.reImbursementdiv li").toArray().map(function(i) {
              return i.id
          }));
      }


      return true;
  }
}).disableSelection();
```